# pass result of function back up the chain so a parent changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a function `PostQuestionForm` calling `signin`. `signin` creates a form. How can I have the form created by `signin` notify `PostQuestionForm` that there was a change.

```
export function PostQuestionForm() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    return (
        <div>
            { creds.username == 'xxx' ?
                    (<div>
                        success
                    </div>) :
                    (<SigninForm />)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Signin

```
export function SigninForm() {

    //formSubmit calls this function
    var credsSubmitHandler = async (event) => {} //creds variable is updated here


return (....form here...)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make create a state for `creds`

**PostQuestionForm**

```
export function PostQuestionForm() {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [creds, setCreds] = useState({})

    return (
        <div>
            { creds.username == 'xxx' ?
                    (<div>
                        success
                    </div>) :
                    (<SigninForm setCreds={setCreds} />)
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Signin**

```
export function SigninForm({ setCreds }) {

    //formSubmit calls this function
    var credsSubmitHandler = async (event) => {
      //... do your business here
      setCreds(result)
    } //creds variable is updated here


return (....form here...)
}
```

Comment: How does this work? How does changing the `creds` property in Signin re-render PostQuestionForm?

Comment: @Rilcon42 when state changes, it cause component to rerender, here state is `creds`, `PostQuestionForm` has that state, and when `creds` changes, `PostQuestionForm` rerenders. You could refer to the classic counter example