# React not re-render when child component updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to have the SigninForm pass the email back to the component that called it (App). Then when email is updated App should re-render. I tried to create the structure given in [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66038575/1634753). However I could not get the App component to update and display the email in my React code.

TLDR: Why isnt the Email displaying on the snippet when I click the button?

```js
function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState();

  return ( 
    <div>
      EMAIL: {email} 
      <br></br> 
      <SigninForm setEmail={setEmail}/> 
    </div>
  )
}

function SigninForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState()

  var credsSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setEmail('me@me.com')
  }
  
  return ( 
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={credsSubmit}>
        <input type='submit' />
      </form> 
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: May you fix the syntax errors in the example?

Comment: Also, why would `App` update? `SigninForm` is not using any props and has its own state

Comment: @evolutionxbox what syntax errors? The snippet editor didnt tell me there were any, and the "Format" button gave me the code you see above..... Should I have done something else?

Comment: Ah I see. I don't think the snippet editor knows how to format JSX.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree it doesnt seem like App should update (Thats what I asked on the linked question). Should I put something like a useEffect hook in App to watch the value of email? I can do that. Will update the example momentarily

Comment: Try removing the `useState` from within `SigninForm`, and change `SinginForm()` to `SigninForm({ setEmail })`?

Comment: I used prettier to format the JSX code a bit better, but it's still throwing an error...

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks that does look better..... It seems like its having trouble on the react import. Im trying to use the latest version from a CDN due to hook changes

Comment: I think that's fixed the snippet. It's rendering now at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState();

  return ( 
    <div>
      EMAIL: {email} 
      <br></br> 
      <SigninForm setEmail={setEmail}/> 
    </div>
  )
}

function SigninForm(props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState()

  var credsSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.setEmail('me@me.com')
  }
  
  return ( 
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={credsSubmit}>
      <input type='submit' />
      </form> 
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

1-in the `App` component you are passing `setEmail` as props to the `SigninForm` this line:

```
<SigninForm setEmail={setEmail}/>
```

2-in the `SigninForm` you are creating a state variable `email` and a setter function to set its value `setEmail` that is this line:

```
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState()
```

in `SigninForm` you were calling `setEmail` thinking that this will update state of `App` component where in reality you were calling the local   `setEmail` not the one you were receiving from the props.

by calling `props.setEmail` you are calling the method that is coming from `App` component not the local one.

and here is the react guide on [components and props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Consider encouraging the `SinginForm` state be removed too?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i am not pretty sure if this is the desired outcome.

Comment: @AlanOmar that worked perfectly, Any chance you could explain what "props" does and why it was so important here? Or tell me what to google?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I took your suggestion and removed the extra email state from the `SigninForm`

Answer (score 1):

```
function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState();
  return ( 
    <div>
      EMAIL: {email} 
      <br></br> 
      <SigninForm setEmail={setEmail}/> 
    </div>
  )
}

function SigninForm(props) {
  var credsSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.setEmail('me@me.com')     // changed this and removed local email state
  }
  
  return ( 
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={credsSubmit}>
        <input type='submit' />
      </form> 
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a button?

```
function App() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState();

  return ( 
    <div>
      EMAIL: {email} 
      <br></br> 
      <SigninForm setEmail={setEmail}/> 
    </div>
  )
}

function SigninForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState()

  var credsSubmit = (event, data) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    props.setEmail(data.email.toLowerCase());
  }
  
  return ( 
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={credsSubmit}>
        <input name="email" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```